# Connect to Microsoft Access Database(.mdb) using AWS Lambda Function .Net

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, ms-access, aws-lambda, oledb

I tried using following code to make connection but AWS Lambda Function threw an error.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=...");

con.Open();
```

Error:

```
System.Data.OleDb is not supported on this platform.: PlatformNotSupportedException
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at AWSLambda1.Function.FunctionHandler(String input, ILambdaContext context) in C:\Users\TestUser\source\repos\AWSLambda1\AWSLambda1\Function.cs:line 35
   at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )
```

Can anyone please help? If OleDb is not supported in Lambda Function then can you please show me a way to connect to Microsoft Access Database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As to the error message, this is not possible. Either refrain from this environment or use another database.

Comment: I don't know what runtime AWS lambda uses but you could see if this method (not using OLEDB) works. But it depends what's in the lambda runtime. https://mrojas.ghost.io/msaccess-in-dotnetcore/

Comment: This https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html says the C# runtime is on .NET Core 2.1. This doesn't have OLEDB. Now I'll read the bit about custom runtimes and see if there is a way to do it.

Comment: This is meant to explain how to create a custom runtime (where you can install ODBC drivers) but I can't make much sense of it. At this stage you should explain what you are actually trying to do, and what options besides AWS Lambda functions you have. You can connect to MS Access in many ways but it seems to be quite difficult from AWS Lambda https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes you are right about we can't connect from AWS Lambda because AWS Lambda uses Linux as OS which does not contain libraries for OleDB or ODBC. So I have used AWS Docker Containers. And instead of OleDB, I have used ODBC(System.Data.Odbc) driver.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: If you have time could you post a brief description of your solution as an answer to benefit everyone?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes I will add my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this running as x64 bit? There is no JET support for x64 bit running process.

If AWS has support for JET, then you will have to force your project to x86 (x32 bits). That means you can't use ANY CPU, nor can you use x64 for the .net project. You have to force the project as x32. However, the rest of your software running on that system, including the web server is likely running as x64 bits.

If your web server is x64, then you have to use a x64 bit version of the JET data engine. There is not x64 for JET, but there is a x64 bit version called ACE, and it can read mdb files. So right now the issue is does the container you using on AWS support JET, and if it does, then you have to ensure you force compile your .net project to x32 bits.